Convergence of a sequence such that $|x_{n+2}-x_{x+1}|\leq C |x_{n+1}-x_n|$ for some $0\leq C < 1$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$?
I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $(x_i)_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $|x_{n+2}-x_{x+1}|\leq C |x_{n+1}-x_n|$ for some $0\leq C < 1$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Show that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence, convergent.

I noticed the following:
As we have
$$|x_{n+2}-x_{x+1}|\leq C |x_{n+1}-x_n|$$
We also have
$$|x_{n+3}-x_{x+2}|\leq C |x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|$$
and hence:
$$|x_{n+3}-x_{x+2}| \leq C^2 |x_{n+1}-x_n|$$
Which we can extend to obtain:
$$|x_{n+2}-x_{x+1}|\leq C^{n+1} |x_{1}-x_{0}|$$

If we have $m>n$, we can write:
$$|x_m-x_n|=|x_m-x_{m-1}+x_{m-1}-x_{n}|\leq |x_m-x_{m-1}|+|x_{m-1}-x_{n}|$$
And we can repeat the process and use the previous inequality to obtain:
$$\begin{align*}|x_m-x_n|&\leq |x_m-x_{m-1}|+|x_{m-1}-x_{n}|+\dots+|x_{n+1}-x_n|\\&\leq (C^{m-1}+C^{m-2+}+\dots+C^{n})|x_1 - x_0|\end{align*}$$
And we can use the geometric series to estimate this sum. Although I believe these observations can be used to prove this, It's not clear to me how to end it. Can you help me?

Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171307/42969 – both found with Approach0

The work you have presented is fine. Indeed, we use the partial geometric sum formula to bound this:
$$|x_m-x_n|\leq (C^{m-1}+C^{m-2}+\ldots+C^n)|x_1-x_0|= \frac{C^n(1-C^{m-n})}{1-C}|x_1-x_0|=\frac{C^n-C^m}{1-C}|x_1-x_0|$$
which tends to zero as $m,n\to\infty$.
